# Dynamically change CORS allowed domains list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, cross-domain, cors

I have a rails server witch expose APIs and i want to allow only some domains to do requests on my api.

I've added the gem rack-cors to my Gemfile and the following code to application.rb

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :put, :delete, :options]
  end
end
```

This code allows every domain to send requests to my server, is there a way to dynamically updates the allowed domains list? Is this a good approach to my problem?

Comment: I'm conscious that his question is very old, but what did you mean by "dynamically"? Did you mean _without requiring a server restart_?

Comment: @jub0bs He wants to extend his origins list, if it's loaded by default from DB/Redis. But in current Rails implementation he needs to restart the server. So the main problem - how to update CORS origins/Rails allowed hosts during runtime.

Comment: @Nike0 Ok. I don't know whether it can be done with Rails, but I'm [personally](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#11-guarantee-configuration-immutability) in favour of requiring a server restart when the CORS configuration must change.

Comment: @jub0bs In that case we'll lost automation process. I'm looking now solution for this and found this question here)